# ClientWindow ID not rendered and ClientWindow is null when using Spring instead of CDI

Tags: spring, jsf, tomcat

I am trying to set Spring project with JSF 2.2 running on Tomcat.
All is working fine but the `ClientWindow` is never activated.
I have added

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>url</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to `web.xml` but I still do not see any URL or hidden field additions to my buttons/links and 
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getClientWindow()` deliverts `NULL`.

If I run a similar project with CDI, I see an activated `ClientWindow`.

There is a small toy project on https://github.com/purplehaze/springuserplay.